# I am novice, writing an app similar to Reddit, and the error I get is: undefined method `user' for #<Topic

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
NoMethodError in Topics#show
```

> > Showing /Users/Tish/code/bloccit/app/views/topics/show.html.erb where line #37 raised:
> >
> > > undefined method `user' for #
> > >       Extracted source (around line #37):

```
34  <%= link_to "New Post", new_topic_post_path(@topic), class: 'btn btn-success' %>  
35  <% end %>
36
37  <% if policy(@topic).destroy? %>
38  <%= link_to "Delete Topic", @topic, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-     danger', 
         data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this topic?' } %> 
         <% end %>
```

> here is schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150128034556) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
t.text     "body"
t.integer  "post_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
```

> model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments 

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def admin?
   role == 'admin'    
  end

 def moderator?
  role == 'moderator'
 end

end
```

> model/comment.rb

```
   class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user

    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

end
```

> The problem shows when I click on a topic, I get an error. Please excuse me ahead of time for not formatting the question correctly!
>
> here is one of the policies:

```
   class TopicPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

   def index?
    true
   end

   def create?
    user.present? && user.admin?
   end

   def update?
    create?
   end

   def destroy?
    user.present? && can_moderate?(user, record)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Knowing what line the error is on, knowing what the method policy does, and showing your topics controller or at least show method could all help

Comment: But I would guess you need a `belongs_to :user` in your Topic model

Comment: Post your User.rb and Topic.rb models

Comment: @TMP: the error was on the line: _ <% if policy(@topic).destroy? %>_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to use the method `user` you need to either create it yourself or add `belongs_to :user` in your model. In this case since your destroy method called `user`, it was erring because it didn't know what to do

Next time try to add more details around your error to start, such as line number or related models/controllers. Your edit made your question look much better, good work.